# Cannot find Facebook.FacebookClient

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I have been working with dotNet since its release about 10 years ago, so I have a fairly good handle on it.
I am working with both VB 2008 and C# 2008.

My goal is to make a connection to FB using a Desktop application using dotNet.
(and from there to interact with fb, without the need of opening a browser.)

It looks to me that fb has changed its protocol once or twice on how to connect, so some of the code examples that I have found may be stale.

Originally I was using an example that connected with "FacebookAuthClient" (this forum), but since I could not see it in the facebook Namespace, I found that it has been removed, in favour of "FacebookClient" - starting with V6.

I have used facebook.dll version 0.2009.5.8,  and version 3.0.1.0,  as well as all the other assemblies that were bundled with it, and searched in the Object Browser (both Visio Studio VB2008, and C#2008)

The latest examples to connect on this forum provide:

var fb = new FacebookClient();  (I have added "using Facebook;" in the class).

I have search http://facebooksdk.net/  and navigating to GitHub, and Microsoft facebook C# SDK - I still can't find the assembly where "Facebook.FacebookClient" exists.

Basically asking the location of the latest depositories for the Facebook C# SDK.

I really appreciate the help.
J.

Comment: Found my own answer, but I need a reputation of 10 to answer my own question, or wait 10 hours, I will post a bit later.

Answer (score 2):

Found my own answer - No wonder I had so much trouble.

I had to build my own facebook.dll using neget.exe (very similar to the apt-get command used in the linux world - I did not expect this).

I actually found my answer in areas I had been, I just ignored the solution because it didn't appear to be what I was looking for.

1. Goto "https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winclient-sdk"
2. Scroll to near bottom of the page look for NuGet.  Look for the link "NuGet.exe Command Line" ("http://nuget.codeplex.com/downloads/get/222685") and click. (or better yet right click and open in new tab).
3. You can choose the NeGet Bootstrapper, or NuGet Command Line (I choose Command Line since my VisioStudio is at 2008).
4. Save the downloaded file "NuGet.exe" - I moved it to "C:\tmp_fb" for easy command line access.
5. Go back to the first web-page (mentioned in step 2), and copy the command 
   "nuget install Facebook.Client -pre" in your clip board.
6. Open a command line shell.  (Click Start, Run, enter "cmd"). Change Directory to the location you saved NuGet.exe, in my case it was c:\tmp-fb.

So just type:    cd c:\tmp-fb

1. Now type:  Install-Package Facebook.Client -pre
2. As it installs you will get a few messages on the screen resolving dependency, etc... and a few Successfully installed.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: it is easier to go to http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook/ and download the .nupkg and extract it using you favorite zip folder. You will need  to login to be able to see the download link. if not here is the direct download link. http://nuget.org/api/v2/package/Facebook/6.4.0 or install this chrome extension. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nutake/ibhhbcaipjilldjkhhblhgdedjgoecap